# Integrate Client-side Validation

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0, client-side-validation

**EDIT**
contacted the author of play-js-validation. Bleeding edge stuff; Play has to be compiled against scala virtualized on to-be-released 2.10, and nested case classes are not yet supported. Really impressive project, I hope it comes to fruition as the prototype does almost exactly what I was hoping for...

Found this:
https://github.com/namin/play-js-validation

Anyone know if there are plans for built-in client-side validation in Play 2.0?

I am currently generating controller, model (with form validation), and dao scala files based on an existing DB schema; would love to include client-side validation as part of that process!

Thanks for clues, insider knowledge, etc.

p.s. Play user group is, to say the least, busy; most posts seem to be completely ignored (of course, many Stackoverflow Play-related questions go unanswered as well, so this thread may be DOA...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no such plans I'm afraid, at least didn't hear about (note: I'm not a dev team member, just Player)

Check [tickets on Play's Lighthouse](https://play.lighthouseapp.com/projects/82401-play-20/overview)

On the other hand I doubt if this fits Play's assumptions at all. Client-side validation is done with some external JS solution which should not be determined by framework, nobody said that it should use ie. jQuery by default.

Finally, the only thing to use client-side validation is just to include the JS libs and add proper attributes to your form fields, ie it will create tag that you can validate with [jQuery Validation plugin](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/):

```
@inputText(entrantForm("identitynumber"),
    '_label->"Identity number",
    'class -> "required",
    'minlength -> "11",
    'maxlength -> "11")
```

Comment: hey, a reply! ;-) +1 for the field helper tip. Play supports Twitter bootstrap, so why not jQuery Validation, the de facto validation plugin used across the board (i.e. as much if not more than Bootstrap)

Comment: Well TB also doesn't fit framework's assumptions :P I don't understand why it's supported (which of course doesn't mean that I condemn that fact :) )

Comment: assume no client-side integration because it is a LOT more work than integrating TB ;-) Ideally the "val foo = Form(mapping("foo"-> text.verifiying(required) ), ...)" server-side form validator would generate the client-side validation snippets; would save a ton of boilerplate. Just got started with Play and...I'm impressed! client-side validation would be a yummy addition...